# how to install commerce_kickstart on an environment with PHP memory_limit less than 128M?

Tags: commerce

I tried the full core install aproach and got a warning that I only had 96M on php `memory_limit`and kickstart needs 128M. tried anyway and sure enough got a memory error at the very end of the installation. I looked around my host and I'm sure I can't change that.

How can I make this installation work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the methods listed [here](http://drupal.org/node/207036) to increase the PHP memory_limit value

If none of those work, you may need a new host for that application.

Comment: I agree with David. Even if you found a workaround to installing Commerce kickstart, it also contains a large number of modules and will require at least 128M to operate on an ongoing basis. You are going to have to increase the amount of memory allocated to your site or get a new host.